# What is the benefit of using DSASignatureFormatter over DSACryptoServiceProvider to generate a signature?

Tags: c#, dsa

I'm using DSA to create a signature for a binary blob, and I'm trying to figure out what I would gain from using the DSASignatureFormatter's CreateSignature(byte[]), rather than just using DSACryptoServiceProvider's CreateSignature(byte[])

As far as I can tell, the only benefit to using the DSASignatureFormatter is that I can specify the hashing algorithm by using SetHashAlgorithm(), and then the formatter takes care of hashing the data for me. In the DSACryptoServiceProvider scenario, I have to pre-hash the data before passing it to the CreateSignature method.

Is there anything else to be gained by using the Formatter?

Answer (score 2):

DSASignatureFormatter is a much more limited class to a full blown encryption algorithm. It is only concerned with signing payload and its inverse (DSASignatureDeformatter) is only concerned with verifying signatures.

I guess if you wanted to switch to RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter one day you would be able to do all the work against the base class and switch fairly easily.

The AsymmetricSignatureFormatter and AsymmetricSignatureDeformatter are simple classes that would be fairly easy to code up anyway and represent a different layer of abstraction to the SymmetricAlgorithm classes.